# Passing php variable to modal twitter bootstrap not working

Tags: php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Hi I'm passing php variable to twitter boostrap modal. but I cant get the right id when I click the link inside the modal. please see code below. 
first I have created a foreach function where data loops second I have created a link to show the modal 3rd I have actions link inside the modal where user can update, delete the data. what I have achieve already is that I can pass the variable of php going to modal actions, but when I try to other rows it shows the same id still.

```
  <table class="table table-condensed table-bordered table-striped volumes">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Director</th>
        <th>Address</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>


<?php

        foreach ($natcco_members as $nattco) {

        $id = $nattco['id'];
        echo "<tr>
              <td>".++$counter."</td>
              <td>".$nattco['director']."</td>
              <td><a href='#' class='b'>".$nattco['agent_name']."</a></td>
              <td>".$nattco['address']."</td>
             </td>";

?>

<!-- Modal HTML -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Choose your actions!</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body" align="center">
                                <a href='update_sub_agent.php?id=<?php echo urlencode(htmlspecialchars($id)) ?>' class='btn btn-success'><i class='icon-pencil'></i> Edit</a> 
                                <a href='owner.php?id=".urlencode(htmlspecialchars($id))."' class='btn btn-info'><i class='icon-user'></i> Owner</a> 
                                <a href='fla.php?id=".urlencode(htmlspecialchars($id))."' class='btn btn-warning'><i class='icon-list-alt'></i> FLA</a>  
                                <a href='delete.php?id=".urlencode(htmlspecialchars($id))."' class='btn btn-danger'><i class='icon-remove'></i> Delete</a> 
           </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

          <?php "</tr>";

    }
}
?>

</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: don't put your Modal inside table content

Comment: Hi @Manwal appreciated, I put <!-- Modal HTML --> outside of my closing </table> but it does not work.

Comment: Can you paste the rendered HTML?

Comment: hi @ICanHasCheezburger please see http://pastebin.com/u1XnKZ5a

Comment: @JaysonLacson Rendered HTML is the output you see on the browser. _Right-click->View source_

Comment: hi @ICanHasCheezburger http://pastebin.com/k5Aj4v50

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have made quite some edits to your code, let's start with what you were doing first:

1. `<td>".$nattco['address']."</td>
            </td>";`

   This has to be `</tr>` instead of `</td>`.
2. You only need one modal box. We will pass the `id` for them through jQuery. So create only 1 static modal box at the end of your table.

Now the things you need to do:

1) Make use of this `$id = $nattco['id'];` as your `<tr id>` so it will be:

```
 $id = $nattco['id'];
 echo "<tr id='".urlencode(htmlspecialchars($id))."'> #...rest of your code
```

2) Give a class for your buttons in the modal box:

```
<a href='update_sub_agent.php' class='btn btn-success edit'><i class='icon-pencil'></i> Edit</a>
                                                 <!-- ^edit class added -->
<a href='owner.php' class='btn btn-info owner'><i class='icon-user'></i> Owner</a>
                                   <!-- ^owner class added -->
<a href='fla.php' class='btn btn-warning fla'><i class='icon-list-alt'></i> FLA</a> 
                                    <!-- ^fla class added -->
<a href='delete.php' class='btn btn-danger delete'><i class='icon-remove'></i> Delete</a>
                                      <!-- ^delete class added -->
```

3) Add `href` and `class to your`` tag :

```
`<td><a href='#myModal' class='b modal-box'>".$nattco['agent_name']."</a></td>`
```

And finally, the jQuery bit:

```
$('a.modal-box').click(function(e){
   id=$(this).closest('tr').attr('id');
   $('.modal-body .edit').attr('href','update_sub_agent.php?id='+id+'');
   $('.modal-body .owner').attr('href','owner.php.php?id='+id+'');
   $('.modal-body .fla').attr('href','fla.php?id='+id+'');
   $('.modal-body .delete').attr('href','delete.php?id='+id+'');
});
```

That's all. This minimizes your code so that modal box is not repeated while dynamically passing `id` of the clicked row.

You can have a look a the demo here:

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/6dz6d/)**

Comment: hi @ICanHasCheezburger modal works, but I didnt get the id in url. for example. edit.php?(id=1) please see rendered html. http://pastebin.com/sTkEk2Zb

Comment: I think there is a problem with jquery or javascript @ICanHasCheezburger

Comment: no errors showing is just that it cant get the row id in the url.

Comment: @JaysonLacson Try wrapping the jQuery function inside `$(document).ready(function(){ //paste here });` and place it after your HTML.

Comment: hi @ICanHasCheezburger sorry my mistake. anyway. it works like a charm now. your like my angel in this earth! :) one more please, could you please delete the DEMO (fullscreen) you have created in your answer? because it contains confidentiality on our part and I don't want to publicize it. thank you so much!

Comment: @JaysonLacson Sure, I will, in fact, we can remove all the paste-bin comments too. And also updated the demo link with all the information removed and just sample data.