# How to pass variables to bootstrap confirm modal button use jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I want to attach a handler to `click` events on the Delete button, which will pop a Confirm modal.
When confirmed it should redirect to `process.php?cid=$cid`.
But how do I pass the variable `$cid` to the modal delete?

Data List:

```
<?php
    foreach($getChannel as $data) {
?>
<div class="btn-group btn-group-solid">
    <a class="btn red" data-toggle="modal" href="#small" id="<?php echo $cid?>">
    <i class="fa fa-trash"></i> Delete </a>
</div>
<?php
    }
?>
```

Modal:

```
<div class="modal fade bs-modal-sm" id="small" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Confirm</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                 Are you sure to delete?
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn green" data-dismiss="modal"  id="delcancel">cancel</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn red" id="del" onclick="process.php?cid=$cid">Go Delete</button>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

How do I use jQuery to receive $cid variables?

```
<button type="button" class="btn red" id="del" onclick="process.php?cid=$cid">Go Delete</button>
```

Comment: I wish i could flag a question twice. You're question has already been asked : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34693206/how-can-i-pass-a-php-variable-to-bootstrap-modal?rq=1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing php variable to modal twitter bootstrap not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23467669/passing-php-variable-to-modal-twitter-bootstrap-not-working)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass $\_GET variables from a link to a bootstrapmodal?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32433765/how-to-pass-get-variables-from-a-link-to-a-bootstrapmodal)

Answer (score 0):

```
<button type="button" class="btn red" id="del" data-cid="<?php echo $cid; ?>">Go Delete</button>
```

Use a custom attribute which holds your `$cid` value

```
$("button[data-cid!='']").click(function() {
    var getCid = $(this).attr("data-cid"); // this returns $cid
    //your statements what you wanna proceed with
});
```

Then use jQuery to utilize your `$cid` value in jQuery, `tag with attribute` selector utilized to target click event upon the button which has the attribute `data-cid`. after targeting click event, used `$(this)` to target clicked current element to retrieve attributes `.attr('data-cid')` value